# creating a view of tables of a different database

Tags: oracle, view

Is it possible to create a view in a database A of tables of another database B? If possible, can somebody please help me, I'm totally clueless.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just use a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm). So, your view would be:

```
create or replace view my_view as
 select some_columns
   from my_table@the_other_database
```

Beware though it's not always that efficient and you may have some problems with queries doing things you don't expect. If there's any volume to the data you're trying to select it might be worth using a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm) instead to take data cross server. Then you can select data from the server you're on currently, which'll  *probably* be a lot quicker.